# How to ignore changes in some folders when developing locally?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using the Go SDK for the Google App Engine (it uses some parts of the Python SDK and calls into `dev_appserver.py` when running `goapp serve`). By default, it seems to watch *all* files and folders for changes. I have a crapload of bower dependencies in the static folder, and the SDK complains that it can't watch that many files.

How to set the dev server to ignore changes in a folder?

**Edit**. Reading `devappserver2/watcher_common.py`, it seems that it ignores directories starting with `.`. I suppose in the worst case scenario, I could prefix folders with `.`, but it's a hack. There should be a configuration option, and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: edit the watcher file so it filters out files you don't need watched. I've already edited the max_file_watched variable.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Sure that's an option, but this might break when updating the SDK. I want to find an option that doesn't require changing the SDK tools.

Comment: there does not seem to be an option for excluding some files at the moment. I hope that the skip_files set will eventually be excluded from watching.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood That's too sad. Thanks for answering.

Comment: Is this still the case? It has been now almost a year? Kinda important functionality as said all kind of npm folders and other library folders eat up a lot of watchers capacity

Comment: skip_files still not working so far

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
Google Cloud SDK 197.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.68
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.63
bq 2.0.31
core 2018.04.06
gsutil 4.30
```

From the [App Engine Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/local-devserver-command), you can pass an argument, `--watcher_ignore_re`, to `dev_appserver.py` when running from the command line.

**Example**

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml --watcher_ignore_re="(.*\.data|.*\.vscode)"
```

This will ignore changes to the `.data` and `.vscode` directories, relative to the directory from which the command is run (*CWD*).

---

### Edit 7th June 2018.

Using:

```
Google Cloud SDK 204.0.0
app-engine-python 1.9.70
app-engine-python-extras 1.9.69
bq 2.0.34
core 2018.06.04
gsutil 4.31
```

The `watcher_ignore_re` seems to not be working anymore.

Rather, what worked for me is to add a `skip_files` directive in the `app.yaml` file as stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files) in the docs. The `dev_appserver.py` command will respect the definitions in this section.

**Example**

Inside `app.yaml` of the project:

```
...
...
skip_files:
# default from GAE
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$

# custom entries

# dev-related files
- ptvsd
- pydev_startup.py
- .pylintrc
- .data
- .vscode

# version control files
- .git
- .gitignore
- .gitattributes

# non-application files
- README.md
- ^(.*/)?.*\.mwb(.bak)?$ # workbench models
```

Now, run project with command:

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml
```

Comment: For those who faced with not implemented support of `watcher_ignore_re` and `skip_files_re` on Windows [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721890/google-app-engine-dev-appserver-py-watcher-ignore-re-flag-is-not-json-serializ/54155850#54155850) with workaround with implementations its support for Windows may be useful

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there is currently no command-line or configuration option to specify files/directories to be ignored by the watcher.

### . (dot) hack

As you've discovered, files and directories beginning with `.` are ignored.  This is a fairly standard convention for many *nix systems.  It is not really scalable however with python projects with many local dependencies.

### Modifying the watcher file

You can modify this file but this too is unfavorable as it makes for very brittle changes and is prone to breaking if updates overwrite the file.

Barring the above workarounds, there's no way to achieve this.  I've also not seen any mention of this being implemented in the [App Engine release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes).  There is however an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9300) on the public issue tracker to have the watcher ignore files specified by the `skip_files` yaml directive.  Feel free to star that issue to get updates regarding its progress.

## EDIT: Jan 4, 2017

### NPM 3

For users of NPM encountering this limitation, you may find it helpful to use NPM v3 as it [resolves dependencies differently](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3).

> npm3 attempts this [mitigate deep trees and redundancy] by installing some secondary dependencies (dependencies of dependencies) in a flat way, in the same directory as the primary dependency that requires it.

This can be very effective for Node users encountering the file watching limitation.

### Frankenserver

Khan Academy has developed a fork of the App Engine devserver called [Frankenserver](https://github.com/Khan/frankenserver).  While I've not explored this option myself, there seems to be a fair amount of support and recent updates to it.  From it's readme:

> frankenserver's biggest advantage over the vanilla SDK is in how it watches the files in your app for changes. It does this much more efficiently by 1) using a native FSEvents-based file watcher on Mac OS X and 2) respecting the skip_files directive in your app.yaml.

Though this is not an official Google solution, it may be a worthwhile workaround for time being if this limitation affects you direly.

Comment: starred the feature request, unfortunately it's been starred for 3 years with acknowledge

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up.  I'll investigate [`Issue 9300`](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9300) to see what's happening with this internally.  I'll also update my answer with some additional workarounds that may be helpful in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the [comment37](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35895450#comment37) in the [`Issue 9300`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35895450) works for me.

In case, the link is not accessible anymore. here is the comment37:

> In theory this code exists now, but there is a bug. It does use the
>   skip_files directive, but instead of matching against relative paths,
>   it uses absolute paths.
>
> So if I have:
>
> skip_files:
>
> - ^node_modules(/.*)?
>
> It will attempt to match
>   /Users/myuser/Projects/myproject/node_modules/ and fail.
>
> Adding an additional entry should fix it and let it skip your
>   node_modules directory:
>
> skip_files:
>
> - ^node_modules(/.*)?
>
> - .*node_modules
>
> This is the hack-workaround I'm using now, which at least allows me
>   the convenience of not needing to go in and edit the gcloud files
>   directly each time they re-release!

highlight of the most important part:

```
skip_files: 
- ^node_modules(/.*)? 
- .*node_modules
```